# Split subarray into separate variable with specified key from multi array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi diemntional array as follow:

```
Array
(
    [0] => transactionType:"for_rent"
    [1] => perPage:15
    [4] => page:1
    [6] => exclusive:true
    [options] => Array
        (
            [0] => has_parking
            [1] => has_climate_control
            [2] => has_pool
        )

)
```

I want to extract `options` array into a separate variable $options and leave remaining array without `options` subarray like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => transactionType:"for_rent"
    [1] => perPage:15
    [4] => page:1
    [6] => exclusive:true
)
```

There must be such php function or an easy way but I can't figure it out.

I tried `extract` function also `array_slice` but can't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply copy the subarray and unset it from the main array:

```
$mainArray = [

    'transactionType:"for_rent"',
    'perPage:15',
    'page:1',
    'exclusive:true',

    'options' => [

        'has_parking',
        'has_climate_control',
        'has_pool'
    ]

];

$options = $mainArray['options'];
unset ($mainArray['options']);

// print_r ($options);
// print_r ($mainArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

As Pippo mentioned you can use unset() function but if options array is always latest
you can also use array_pop() function (detailed: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)
example:

```
$array = ["transactionType" => "for_rent", "perPage" => 15, "page" => 1, "options" => ["has_parking", "has_climate_control", "has_pool"]]; 
$options = array_pop($array);
print_r($array);
print_r($options);
```